# having problems with the home page S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, home-screen, samsung-touchwiz

My S4 has been rooted 2 weeks ago,and today it locked up and I cannot do anything on it, cannot open settings, cannot receive phone calls, cannot send text messages. the home page is unresponsive, and when i try to press any buttons the only thing that comes up is a message saying "touchwiz in not responding". The computer is now not reading the phone. So not sure what to do, please advice. Thank you!

A friend rooted the phone for me, so not sure how it was done, and my friend is out of the country now.Did not change any settings.

Comment: What have you used root to do? Did you change any system settings that aren't normally accessible, overwrite system files, or use any apps that use root? Please [edit] your question to say, so that we have a chance of working out what could be wrong.

Comment: A friend rooted the phone for me, so not sure how it was done, and my friend is out of the country now.Did not change any settings.

Comment: did not even install any new apps since it was done. The phone worked fine till today. It was responding slow, so I restarted it, and now nothing works.

Comment: Did u try rebooting ?

Answer (score 2):

Try factory setting option in settings.If it doesnt work,try updating it to next version os and again root it if necessary.I would suggest to just root it again it may happen that rooting process is not been completely successfull.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did a factory reboot, but the phone still does not work. It does not go pass the initial page where you choose the language options when I turn it on, the screen keeps "shaking", and I am unable to complete the original set up.